# Need Suggestions for a Good CD/DVD burner that also mounts .ISO files

Tags: iso-image, burning, optical-drive, virtual-drive

I've been looking for this for a while now. I'd like a freeware program that burns all CDs and DVDs, and also mounts and runs .ISO files on virtual drives without requiring any additional software. Is there anything like this out there?

Comment: What OS? Linux does this easily.

Answer (score 3):

you can use virtual clone drive http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html for iso mounting.

and imgburn for burning http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download

Comment: Exactly what I use